# Discarding an aspect instance before the object ("this" or "target") gets garbage collected

Tags: aspectj

I know that aspect instances (due to perthis or pertarget) get automatically disposed along with their object, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing this programmatically at any point of the object life cycle. The aim is to have more fine grained control over the overheads of aspect code.

Consider the following example where I want to check that for each account there is an initial deposit before the first withdraw. Note that once I observe the first deposit then there is no need to keep the aspect instance any further:

```
aspect accounting perthis (execution(Account.new(..))) {    

after () : execution(* Account.deposit(..))
{
         //fine... discard aspect instance
}   

before () : execution(* Account.withdraw(..))
{
    assert first_deposit:"Cannot withdraw before a first deposit";  
}
```

Comment: This sounds like you want to introduce more overhead instead of avoiding it. Why would you want to do something manually which is done automatically? How do you want to decide when an aspect instance is no longer needed even though it is still in scope? How about just optimising your per* conditions instead, so the aspect instance does not live longer than necessary?

Comment: For example imagine having an object which is no longer of interest (from an aspect perspective) after a particular method call. How can you modify the per* condition to modify the duration of an aspect instance? Doesn't it only decide which instances are created? Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you are. But instead of theorising, how about editing your question, providing a concrete example which then we can discuss and see which ways there are to achieve what you want? Maybe you have something specific in mind, but maybe you are stuck in a dead end? I will be glad to help if you provide something more tangible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the aspect itself is really the problem?  An aspect instance will be fairly small if it doesn't contain much state.  And if your aspect instance does contain significant amount of state, you'd be better off just `null`ing out the fields in the aspect instead of trying to disconnect the aspect from the instance.

Comment: but disconnecting the aspect also gives the advantage of stopping matching any events for that given object.

Comment: Not necessarily. or at least the performance boost is probably negligible.  The byte code hooks are already in the classes. There are some pointcuts that are statically determined and others that are dynamic.  The pointcuts you have are all static, which means that there are no runtime tests for applicability.  And just disconnecting the aspect will not remove the bytecode.  All it will do is prevent the advice from being invoked.  If it's performance that you're concerned about, then measure it to see if it's a real problem before you do anything drastic.

Comment: Yes, I think generally the performance gain is negligible but even in the simple example above, the implementation would have to be modified to cater for the fact that the aspect does not get discarded. It is the advice that performance might be an issue rather than the AspectJ implementation itself. Even if performance is not enough of a motivation, I think that design-wise it is nice to be able to discard an aspect at some stage. I find it strange that nobody every felt this need.